# what is the difference about & and as_ref in rust

Tags: rust

When I write Rust code, I sometimes find that I can use `&val` to get a reference, and sometimes I can use `val.as_ref()`. Does `&val` support base types like:

- integers,
- `&str`
- `String`
- `Vec`
- arrays,
- structs,
- enums

and `val.as_ref()` works on complex data types? What is the key difference between using `&val` and `val.as_ref()`?

Comment: I have edited your question to improve readability and clarity. I'm not sure what you mean by "base types" though... In your list you included basically every possible type lol. I wonder if we can improve the clarity so it is more useful to other people? Thanks!

Comment: Just a point, `&val` works on *everything* in Rust: if the type of `val` is `T` then it will create a `&T`. There may be some confusion because `&T` can *coerce* to some `&U` depending on `T` and `U`. But that doesn't conflate with what the `&` itself does.

Answer (score 4):

`.as_ref()` is helpful when used on a `T` it provides something different from `&T`; this is especially useful in order to accept various types in a generic context.

For example, on [this page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html#implementors) we can see that `.as_ref()` on a `String` provides a `&str`, on a `Vec` it provides a slice, `PathBuf` gives `&Path`...

We can find such a usage on [`File::open()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.open) for example, where a `String`, a `&str`, a `PathBuf`... can be passed.
Internally, `.as_ref()` is invoked on the parameter in order to obtain a `&Path` in the end.

Comment: I'll add the `AsRef` is better reserved for generic usages. Almost any usage in non-generic context has better alternatives.